# Subtract 30 days from current date in where clause

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

In my where clause i want to get only the records that have today's date and the last 30 days records. so i would want 3-29-19 through 4-29-19 records
but i need this a rolling date so tomorrow it would be 3-30 through 4-30-19
Basically pulling up the last 30 days worth of records.

curdate() gets me the current date in advantage sql.  im thinking maybe a between clause or something.

dateadd(dd,-30,curdate()),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADS allows you to do straight math on dates (if you've got an actual date column in the table), so you can use

```
WHERE datecol between curdate() - 30 and curdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be something like:

```
where datecol >= timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY, -30, current_date())
```